# Math.pow strange results

Tags: java, android, math, floating-point, ieee

I'm working on a mortgage calculation equation and I'm getting differing results from Math.pow() and I don't know why.

Here is the test setup:

```
double interestRatePercent = 7;
double monthlyInterestRate = (interestRatePercent / 100) / MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
int numberOfPayments = loanTermInYears * MONTHS_PER_YEAR;

Log.i(TAG, String.format("monthlyInterestRate: %f", monthlyInterestRate));
Log.i(TAG, String.format("numberOfPayments: %d", numberOfPayments));
Log.i(TAG, "  ");

Log.i(TAG, "Hardcoded result:");
double hardcodedResult = Math.pow(1.0 + 0.005833, numberOfPayments);
Log.i(TAG, String.format("(1 + 0.005833)^360 = %f", hardcodedResult));
Log.i(TAG, "  ");

Log.i(TAG, "Parameterized result:");
double paramResult = Math.pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments);
Log.i(TAG, String.format("(1 + %f)^%d = %f", monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments, paramResult));
Log.i(TAG, "  ");

Log.i(TAG, "BigDecimal result:");
BigDecimal bigResult = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate);
bigResult = bigResult.pow(numberOfPayments);
Log.i(TAG, String.format("(1 + %f)^%d = %f", monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments, bigResult));
Log.i(TAG, "  ");
Log.i(TAG, "  ");
```

Here is the test results:

```
monthlyInterestRate: 0.005833
numberOfPayments: 360

Hardcoded result:
(1 + 0.005833)^360 = 8.115529

Parameterized result:
(1 + 0.005833)^360 = 8.116497

BigDecimal result:
(1 + 0.005833)^360 = 8.116497
```

Only the hard-coded result is correct.  Both the Math.pow and BigDecimal.pow results are bad.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're rounding in your hardcoded result...

Comment: Actually, only the hard coded result is wrong ;)

Comment: I was going to say exactly the same thing, Simon.

Comment: All of those comments are correct.  For the record, I followed this article which made me think my parameterized results were bad: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/calculate-monthy-mortgage-payments-9620.html - still trying to decide if I should be rounding operations like they did there - Google also decided to round some numbers when I ran them through which didn't help the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal bigResult = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate);`

When you are creating your BigDecimal, you'll get loss of precision, since `1.0 + monthlyInterestRate` will lose precision.  To get better precision, create a `BigDecimal` for 1.0, then use the `add()` method to add it to another `BigDecimal` with the value 0.005833.  Then use the `BigDecimal` `pow()` function.

In other words, construct the `BigDecimal` from simpler `BigDecimals` not `int` or `double` types.

Comment: the issue has ended up being more about how financial numbers are typically calculated (in terms of precision), but I think this answer is important and using BigDecimal everywhere seems to be a good solution for keeping complete accuracy.

Comment: It's true that using `BigDecimal` you get precise results, but the 15 digits of precision given by `double` would be enough here (like they are for most purposes).

Answer (score 6):

7/100/12 is  approximately 0.00583333333, not 0.005833. When you use %f you see only 6 digits after the decimal point by default.

Comment: The actual double is 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125

Comment: So is this entire article producing a bad result due to rounding error? http://homeguides.sfgate.com/calculate-monthy-mortgage-payments-9620.html

It finds a result of $665 for the full calculation where I'm finding $587 for the full calculation using BigDecimal for everything.

Comment: Mortgage interest rates are typically rounded to 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Rounded to 4 digits after every operation?  That sounds like a huge problem...there's an exponent here of 360 which means a lot of inaccuracy is accumulating...in fact in this case the difference between infinite precision and 4 decimal places is about $100/mo

Comment: It's more complicated but at least you get a fairly good estimate. For example, monetary amounts are rounded to the smallest denomination (cents, pennies) in every operation because you can't pay a fraction of a cent.

Comment: Joni, that would be good rationale for truncating the final result...but when you're multiplying a value 360 times, how can someone reasonably truncate the value that's getting multiplied?

Comment: For x close to 0, (1+x)^k is approximately 1+kx, so the difference ends up not being 360 times larger. Here the difference is so small to begin with that the end result is correct to the dollar. On the other hand, in the article you have found the mortgage grows 0.5833% interest each month. That translates to 7.22% interest per year, so the bank is charging more than the advertised 7%.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy is due to rounding of 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125, the actual value of monthlyInterestRate, to 0.005833 in the hard coded result calculation. For convenience, I modified the program to use System.out.println. I changed the output of monthlyInterestRate to print it exactly, and then used that value in the hard coded calculation. The output was:

```
monthlyInterestRate: 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125
numberOfPayments: 360

Hardcoded result:
(1 + 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125)^360 = 8.116497

Parameterized result:
(1 + 0.005833)^360 = 8.116497

BigDecimal result:
(1 + 0.005833)^360 = 8.116497
```

Here is the modified program:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double interestRatePercent = 7;
        int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
        int loanTermInYears = 30;
        double monthlyInterestRate = (interestRatePercent / 100)
                / MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
        int numberOfPayments = loanTermInYears * MONTHS_PER_YEAR;

        // System.out.println(String.format("monthlyInterestRate: %f",
        // monthlyInterestRate));
        System.out.println("monthlyInterestRate: "
                + new BigDecimal(monthlyInterestRate));
        System.out.println(String.format("numberOfPayments: %d",
                numberOfPayments));
        System.out.println("  ");

        System.out.println("Hardcoded result:");
        double hardcodedResult = Math
                .pow(1.0 + 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125,
                        numberOfPayments);
        System.out
                .println(String
                        .format("(1 + 0.005833333333333333599324266316443754476495087146759033203125)^360 = %f",
                                hardcodedResult));
        System.out.println("  ");

        System.out.println("Parameterized result:");
        double paramResult = Math.pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate,
                numberOfPayments);
        System.out.println(String.format("(1 + %f)^%d = %f",
                monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments, paramResult));
        System.out.println("  ");

        System.out.println("BigDecimal result:");
        BigDecimal bigResult = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate);
        bigResult = bigResult.pow(numberOfPayments);
        System.out.println(String.format("(1 + %f)^%d = %f",
                monthlyInterestRate, numberOfPayments, bigResult));
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
}
```